# Prevent Certain CRUD Operations on Laravel Eloquent Models

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5

Is there an easy way to prevent certain CRUD operations from being performed on an Eloquent model?

How I'm doing it now (from memory, I think I'm missing an argument to be compatible with Eloquent's `save()`, but that's not important):

```
<?php

class Foo extends Eloquent {

    public function save()
    {
        // Prevent Foo from being updated.
        if (!empty($this->id)) {
            throw new \Exception('Update functionality is not allowed.');
        }

        parent::save();
    }

}
```

In this case, these models should not be allowed to be updated under any circumstance, and I want my app to explode should something try to update them. Is there a cleaner way to do this without overriding Eloquent's `save()` method?

Comment: You could setup filablle fields, and made them not nullablle when you set up the databse, doing such a thing breaks lot of good principles.

On Laravel 5 you can create FormRequests http://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-form-requests#4.-create-your-formrequest

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In addition to @AlanStorm's answer, here's a comprehensive info:

1. You can setup global listener for all the models:

   ```
   Event::listen('eloquent.saving: *', function ($model) {
     return false;
   });
   ```
2. Or for given model:

   ```
   Event::listen('eloquent.saving: User', function ($user) {
     return false;
   });
   // or
   User::saving(function ($user) {
     return false;
   });

   // If it's not global, but for single model, then I would place it in boot():
   // SomeModel
   public static function boot()
   {
      parent::boot();

      static::saving(function ($someModel) {
         return false;
      });
   }
   ```
3. For read-only model you need just one `saving` event listener returning false, then all: `Model::create`, `$model->save()`, `$model->update()` will be rejected.
4. Here's the list of all Eloquent events: `booting`, `booted`, `creating`, `created`, `saving`, `saved`, `updating`, `updated`, `deleting`, `deleted` and also `restoring` and `restored` provided by `SoftDeletingTrait`.

Answer (score 7):

Eloquent's [event system](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#model-events) allows you to **cancel** a write operation by

1. Listening for the `creating, updating, saving, or deleting` events
2. Returning false from your event callback.

For example, to prevent people from creating new model objects, something like this

```
Foo::creating(function($foo)
{
    return false; //no one gets to create something
});
```

in your `app/start/global.php` file would do the job.